# bash: Changing extension of all the header files in a folder

Tags: bash, recursion, symlink

I want to create symbolic links that point to all the header files in my folder.

For example,

```
ln -s ctype.h ctype.SUNWCCh
```

The name of the symlinks should be the same, except that they have the "SUNWCCh" extension. Also, there are many header files so I would like to do it recursively. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using pure [bash4](/questions/tagged/bash4) :

```
shopt -s globstar

for i in **/*.h; do
    ln -s "$i" "${i%.h}.SUNWCCh"
done
```

Since bash4, `**` stands for *recursive* if you enable it with `shopt -s globstar`

Comment: thank you! it works. Do you mind explain a little bit about what you did? What is `shopt -s globstar` for? And if I want to do it in a different folder, do I put **/./test/*.h or something?

Comment: Actually I want to remove the ".h". Is that possible?

Comment: Added new requirement and better explanation